# How can I parse this text which is in column format, in python script to give specific output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in python scripting and trying to parse the below command output which is in column format, to show :

Text to be parsed:

```
    Neighbor        V           AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
10.0.10.101     4         1024      80      87        1    0    0 01:17:25        0
10.0.11.101     4         1024      92      91        1    0    0 down        0
```

Output format:

```
Neighbor:10.0.10.101 is up
Neighbor:10.0.11.101 is down
```

Edit - 1
Thanks for your suggestion, the code I mentioned in my earlier comment is dynamic output from a command in cisco switch, this is my code below, when I run this script, it needs to dynamically read the output which is in column format and show me if neighbor is up or down, so the neighbor status is not constant it will be changing from up or down, if it is up then time (example - 01:17:25) will be shown or if it is down string ‘down’ will be shown in output

```
from __future__ import print_function
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko
import re
status = open(r'E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-status.txt','w')
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = status
host = '10.0.10.100'
platform = 'cisco_ios'
username = 'javed'
password = 'cisco'
device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
output = device.send_command('terminal length 0')
output = device.send_command('enable')
bgp_status = device.send_command('show ip bgp summary | be N')


for neighbor_status in bgp_status.split('\n'):
    if 'down' in neighbor_status:
        print(f"{neighbor_status} is down")
    else:
        print('All neighbors are up')
        break
status.close()
```

Comment: How do you determine if something is up or down?

Comment: in the column Up/Down - if there is time format (01:17:25) then it is up, or if it is down then this column will have string 'down'.

Comment: What search terms did you try and what did you find? Why didn't those results help you?

Comment: `df['Up/Down']=df['Up/Down'].replace('.*\\d:.*','Up',regex=True))` should solve your issue

Comment: or rather `'Neigbour: '+df['Neighbor']+' is '+df['Up/Down'].replace('.*\\d:.*','Up',regex=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who commented their suggestions, I have written the script after a little research, hope this script may help some network engineer like me in the future:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-status.txt', delim_whitespace=True , header=None)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row[8] == 'Down':
        print (f"Neighbor {row[0]} is down")
    else:
        pass
```

This gives an output of BGP neighbor if it is down:

example:

Neighbor 10.0.11.101 is down

Neighbor 10.0.10.103 is down